# Excel two types of data in the same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to have a list of values in one cell, while when the user looks at it shows text, and when I read this cell I will have a number.

**Example:**

In cell: `A1:`, list of options are: `TCP, UDP`, where `TCP=0, UDP=1`

I will do in another cell `"=A1+4"`, I will get either `0` or `1` from A1 plus 4

Comment: Sounds like you need a lookup table of some sort to convert the text to numbers.  What have you tried?

Comment: Are TCP and UDP values in just one cell or separate cells? If A1 contains "TCP=0, UDP=1" string, you cannot have a 0 or 1 by adding 4 to this string. Could you provide a sample data of what you have and desired output?

Comment: All I want to do is show this Excel to group of people so that they will see UDP/TCP for easy reading, and if I will do some manipulations on the cell I would like to get the numeric values of it. For example "sum"

Comment: I was going to say use the custom number format of `[=1]U\DP;[=0]TCP`, but how would `=A1+4` return 0 or 1 if the value held in A1 is already 0 or 1?  Surely it would return 4 or 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom number format of `[=1]U\DP;[=0]TCP`

- Right click the cell `A1`.
- In the *Number* tab of the *Format Cells* dialog box select the *Custom* category.
- Add `[=1]U\DP;[=0]TCP` as the *Type* and press OK.

Now when you enter data into cell `A1` you'll get:

- When 1 is entered you'll see *UDP*,
- When 0 is entered you'll see *TCP*.
- Any other number will return *#########*.
- Text will display as normal.

Enter `=A1+4` in another cell and it automatically picks up the format from `A1` so change the format back to `General`.

- `0` returns 4
- `1` returns 5
- `2` displays 6 in your formula cell, and *########* in `A1` so may need to allow for that.
  But, if you've got *Data Validation* to allow a *List* of *0,1* then problem solved.

[Custom number formats tutorial on ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/custom-number-formats)